# Зависимость Androidx и Google Framework

Tags: android, google-play, androidx

Я хотел бы писать приложения которые выглядят современно и работают на большинстве устройств (т.е. начиная с API 21 Lollipop). Более того чтобы программа не требовала последних сервисов гугл, вернее чтобы вообще их не требовала.(Если стратегия неверна поправьте пожалуйста, в том смысле что имеет ли смысл писать для API 21 т.к. существует API 29).

Для этого как я понял существует androidx. Возникает несколько вопросов на это счет.

1. Требует ли Androidx последнюю версию Google Play? Насколько я понял да, но внутри androidx есть пакет support и вот уже он не требует и возникает второй вопрос.
2. Как на свежей версии Android Studio создавать проекты с библиотекой androidx.support? Прикладываю скриншоты. Нужно ли ставить галочку в android studio а потом мигрировать на androidx или есть способ сразу его использовать?
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. неясно как вы эти вещи связали. Были библиотеки support, которые выполняли свою функцию. Потом их заменили на androidx, которые их частично дублировали, просто под другим названием. Одновременно использовать и support, и androidx в одном проекте нереально, ни конфликтуют. Соответственно, и одно в другом не находится. Что имеется ввиду под версией Google Play я не понял, если androdi SDK - нет, никаких прямых связей между sdk и androdix нет, библиотеки androidx можно использовать с любыми версиями sdk 15+
2. Не ставьте галочку, она нужна тем, кто привык к саппорту или пишет что-то для старого проекта где уже используется саппорт библиотеки. Для новых приложений нет никакого смысла их использовать. Просто без галочки у вас автоматом будут использоваться androidx библиотеки. Например, создав пустую активити там будет лежать толкьо один элемент - ConstrintLayout из androidx.

Если вы ставите минимальный sdk 21, то ваша программа будет работать на всем что имеет андроид 5.0 и выше. Если вы используете что-то, что требует sdk выше, то студия вам об этом сообщит и не даст скомпилиться так просто.

TargetSDK и compileSdk ставить лучше максимальный возможный. Во-первых, Google Play в какой-то момент перестает принимать новые приложения, скомпиленные не под самый свежий андроид, и вы просто не сможете выложить новую версию с compileSDK 28. Придется ее менять и подгонять код под соответствующие изменения, а изменения могут быть довольно серьезные. Так что чем раньше вы поставите максимальный compileSDK, тем лучше. В общем, если сильно грубо, то minSDK - это граница снизу, compile и target  - граница сверху. Нижнюю ставьте где хотите, а вот верхнюю ставьте максимально возможную если нет явных проблем из-за этого

Сервисы гугл не используются никак, если вы сами их внутри программы не используете. Ваше приложение может быть собрано в апк/бандл и установленно на любую сборку андроид, а сборку андроида вы можете сделать сами из открытых исходных кодов.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ. В замешательство меня ввело несколько вещей: первое - не все приложения могут работать без google play. То есть они впринципе не запустятся на телефоне без gapps. Как пример могу привести любой сервис google. Ну или если там они используются напрямую то взять например игру True Skate (вспомнил только ее хотя проблемы были и с другими. Второе - галочка. Там написано will prevent you from using latest google play services. Но теперь вприципе понятно, спасибо большое